How to encrypt with preserving the format alphanumeric texts
How to do FPE (format preserving encryption) on a text like 'A123456' , if the encryption preserved the format I should get a string with a char than 6 digits , for example 'Z655432' , I used the python library FF3 , so I split the string  'A123456' to 'A' and '123456' and I apply the FF3cipher to each string , well here I find the minimum characters problem so I have to do some padding on 'A', the problem is when u do padding u lost the format, u wont get the format that u want.
I tried padding but the format is not preserved, I tried the pyffx library that don't have the minimum character requirement but apparently its not secure , it does not have the NIST requirements
from ff3 import FF3Cipher

key = "2DE79D232DF5585D68CE47882AE256D8"
tweak = "CB92D080979564"
alphabet = "AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN"
cipher = FF3Cipher.withCustomAlphabet(key, tweak, alphabet)
def pad_to_min_length_alp(text, min_len):
    pad_char = 'A'
    if len(text) < min_len:
        return text + pad_char * (min_len - len(text))
    return text
plaintext = 'A'
padded_plaintext = pad_to_min_length_alp(plaintext, cipher.minLen)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(padded_plaintext)
print(f"Encrypted value: {ciphertext}")

result : Encrypted value: SPVVY
so A has been encrypted to a 5 characters string
the format is not preserved

I have noticed it's not straightforward to convert among an original message(1 letter + 6 decimal digits), a number in [0, 26000000), and a string of 4 digits with radix 72, for some users. And it motivated me for answering the question.
The size of the message space is 26000000. So you need to encrypt an integer in [0, 26000000). Because the size is not an integral exponentiation of an integer, you need the cyclic walking, instead of splitting. I suggest using radix 72, because 724 is close to and larger than 26000000.
Because the ff3 library does not support a number as an input, you should convert an original message to a number, and then convert it to a string of 4 digits with radix 72. Let the digits of radix 72 are ''.join(chr(e) for e in range(72)). When encrypting 'Z123456' for example, it is converted to 25123456 = 67*72**3 + 22*72**2 + 24*72 + 64, and then to '\x43\x16\x18\x40'. You need to encrypt this string with the ff3, and convert the output ciphertext to a number. You need to encrypt again if the decoded number is larger than 26000000 - 1. This is the cyclic walking.
The following is an example of the implementation.
import math
import ff3

RADIX = 72
MAX_NUM = 26*1000000 - 1
N_DIGITS = math.ceil(math.log(MAX_NUM + 1) / math.log(RADIX))
DIGITS = ''.join(chr(e) for e in range(RADIX))

def msg_to_num(msg):
    return (ord(msg[0]) - ord('A')) * 1000000 + int(msg[1:])

def num_to_msg(num):
    q, r = divmod(num, 1000000)
    return '%c%06d' % (q + ord('A'), r)


def num_to_digits(num):
    digits = [None] * N_DIGITS
    for i in range(N_DIGITS):
        num, r = divmod(num, RADIX)
        digits[N_DIGITS-1 - i] = DIGITS[r]
    return ''.join(digits)

def digits_to_num(digits):
    num = 0
    for i in range(N_DIGITS):
        num = num * RADIX + DIGITS.index(digits[i])
    return num


cipher = ff3.FF3Cipher.withCustomAlphabet(
    b'key0123456789012'.hex(), b'tweak012'.hex(), DIGITS)
def encrypt(pt):
    num = msg_to_num(pt)
    while True:
        num = digits_to_num(cipher.encrypt(num_to_digits(num)))
        if num <= MAX_NUM:
            break
    return num_to_msg(num)

def decrypt(ct):
    num = msg_to_num(ct)
    while True:
        num = digits_to_num(cipher.decrypt(num_to_digits(num)))
        if num <= MAX_NUM:
            break
    return num_to_msg(num)

pt = 'Z123456'
ct = encrypt(pt)
print('ct:', ct)
pt2 = decrypt(ct)
print('pt2:', pt2)

